# Why does python's lambda function not resample from a distribution?

Tags: python, numpy

Python's lambda function does not resample from a distribution when applied on an array; e.g. when using:

```
f1 = lambda x: -3 + 0.75*x + numpy.random.randn()
```

The proper way would be to use a map() and thereby 'map' the lambda function on the array.

However, one can easily apply a lambda function on an array. 
**I'm asking how that's working but the function is not resampling.**

a MVP:

```
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(1)

f1 = lambda x: -3 + 0.75*x + numpy.random.randn()  # dummy with random part
f2 = lambda x: -3 + 0.75*x  # dummy w/o random part 

# dummy data
x = numpy.arange(10)

f1(x) - f2(x)
>> array([1.62434536, 1.62434536, 1.62434536, 1.62434536, 1.62434536,
1.62434536, 1.62434536, 1.62434536, 1.62434536, 1.62434536])

numpy.var(f1(x) - f2(x))  # almost 0
```

So, I'd expect a variance greater close to 1. The example is an evidence that the lambda function is just sampling on the first element and then does not change the random part anymore.

Thanks for your explanation !!

Comment: You already have answers to your question below, but as a side comment: when you bind an anonymous function to a symbol, it's no longer anonymous.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `lambda`, which you shouldn't be using in this case since you are assigning the result to a name (the **only** purpose of lambda expressions being to allow you to use anonymous functions)

Comment: thanks @PMende and @juanpa.arrivillaga! I found the syntax quit handy for a short function. do you have best practices in that case ? - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with how you have defined the lambda function `f1`:

```
f1 = lambda x: -3 + 0.75*x + numpy.random.randn()
```

Here `numpy.random.rand()` returns a scalar. So you have `-3 + 0.75 * x` (a vector) + `numpy.random.randn()` (a scalar) - this results is broadcasting the scalar to match the shape of `x` - which means the same scalar value is added to each member of the vector.

So `f1(x)` is some vector + some random number added to each element,
`f2(x)` is the some vector minus the random added.

If you subtract them, you'll get a vector with just the random part broadcasted.

To fix this, you should generate a `randn()` with the same shape as `x`

```
f1 = lambda x: -3 + 0.75*x + numpy.random.randn(*x.shape)
```

Result:

```
f1(x) - f2(x) = [ 1.62434536 -0.61175641 -0.52817175 -1.07296862  0.86540763 -2.3015387
  1.74481176 -0.7612069   0.3190391  -0.24937038]
var() = 0.9982804180510148
```

[randn() docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your function `f1` is running the `randn` function once and broadcasting to the entire array. If you want different random numbers for each element give it a size equal to `x`:

```
f1 = lambda x: -3 + 0.75*x + numpy.random.randn(x.size)
```

With that,

```
numpy.var(f1(x) - f2(x))  # almost 0
```

will be about `1`

Answer (score 0):

You add a scalar to an array, which means the same element is added to each element in the array.

Consider

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a + 1
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```